# Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver, NHibernate, Version=4.0.0.4000, Culture=neutral,

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, configuração, fluent-nhibernate

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação com N**Hibernate e Fluent NHibernate.** Estou tendo problemas com as configurações do meu **App.config**. Não sei o exatamente o que existe de errado nas minhas configurações.

Estou recebendo essa Exception:

**NHibernate.HibernateException: Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver, NHibernate, Version=4.0.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4.**

**Meu App.config está dessa forma:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.122.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppDS" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="[Minha connectionString]" />
    <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="[Minha connectionString]" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SchemaAppDS" value="ENERGISA_DESENV" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle09gDialect</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string_name">AppDS</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
```

**Minha StackTrace está assim:**

```html
Test Name: TestMethod1
Test FullName: NHibernate_Test.UnitTest1.TestMethod1
Test Source: c:\Users\misantos\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\NHibernate\NHibernate-Test\UnitTest1.cs : line 19
Test Outcome: Failed
Test Duration: 0:00:00

Result Message: 
Unable to create instance of class NHibernate_Test.UnitTest1. Error: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Common.Service.SubstationService", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: Calling constructor Common.Repository.SubstationRepository().
Exception is: FluentConfigurationException - An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.


-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving Common.Service.SubstationService,(none)
  Resolving parameter "repository" of constructor Common.Service.SubstationService(Common.Repository.Interface.ISubstationRepository repository)
    Resolving Common.Repository.SubstationRepository,(none) (mapped from Common.Repository.Interface.ISubstationRepository, (none))
    Calling constructor Common.Repository.SubstationRepository()
 ---> FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

 ---> NHibernate.HibernateException: Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver, NHibernate, Version=4.0.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Uma exceção foi acionada pelo destino de uma chamada. ---> System.ArgumentException: Não foi possível localizar o Provedor de Dados .Net Framework solicitado. Talvez ele não esteja instalado..
Result StackTrace: 
em System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
   em NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver..ctor(String providerInvariantName, String driverAssemblyName, String connectionTypeName, String commandTypeName)
   em NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver..ctor()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    em System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   em System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   em System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   em System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   em System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   em NHibernate.Bytecode.ActivatorObjectsFactory.CreateInstance(Type type)
   em NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    em NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
   em NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
   em NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2 settings)
   em NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory.BuildSettings(IDictionary`2 properties)
   em NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSettings()
   em NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   em FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    em FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()
   em Common.Models.DataContext.SessionFactoryHelper.CreateSessionFactory() na c:\Users\misantos\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\NHibernate\Common\Models\DataContext\SessionFactoryHelper.cs:linha 35
   em Common.Repository.SubstationRepository..ctor() na c:\Users\misantos\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\NHibernate\Common\Repository\SubstationRepository.cs:linha 20
   em lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )
   em Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context)
   em Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   em Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   em Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   em Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey)
   em Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context)
   em lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )
   em Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context)
   em Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   em Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   em Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   em Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    em Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
   em Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
   em Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides)
   em Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve[T](IUnityContainer container, ResolverOverride[] overrides)
   em NHibernate_Test.TestBase.Resolve[T]() na c:\Users\misantos\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\NHibernate\NHibernate-Test\TestBase.cs:linha 21
   em NHibernate_Test.UnitTest1..ctor() na c:\Users\misantos\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\NHibernate\NHibernate-Test\UnitTest1.cs:linha 15
```

**O que estou fazendo de errado?**

Comment: Você tem o driver / client instalado na máquina onde está servindo a aplicação? E se não me falha a memória, você também precisa adicionar a referência da dll do oracle no seu projeto. (Oracle.DataAcess.dll)

Comment: Sim tenho o driver client instalado na máquina. Eu não tinha o Oracle.DataAcess.dll, Instalei-o na versão 4.112.3.0. Porém está dando uma nova Exception. **Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client.**

Comment: Segundo esse post no stack em inglês, pode ser a versão do Oracle Data Provider que não suporta 64 bits, o camarada resolveu mudando o target de Any CPU para x86. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728521/could-not-create-the-driver-from-nhibernate-driver-oracledataclientdriver-with

Comment: Obrigado, mas isso não resolveu pra mim. Deixei apenas meu projeto de **Teste** em Any CPU, pois do contrário os teste unitários não aparecem.

Answer (score 0):

Vá até References e selecione o arquivo oracle.dataaccess. Depois vá até propriedades e altera a propriedade Copy Local para True.
Para mim, funcionou.